# Проверка, существует ли такой mail и пароль в базе данных

Tags: c#

Я подключился к базе данных, как мне теперь проверить существует ли такой mail и пароль,если нет то закрыть программу.

---

У меня в базе данных есть таблицы называются mail и password,

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["MydataBASE"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: Нашел код, но не знаю что с ним делать: string sql = $"SELECT COUNT(email, password) FROM dle_users WHERE email = your_user_name AND password = your_password";

Comment: Вы название свой БД знаете? Пытались хотя бы загуглить "c# получить данные из {название вашей БД} "?

Comment: Да я знаю название

Comment: в app config  такие данные <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MydataBASE" connectionString="Data Source=IP_адрес_хостинга;Initial Catalog=имя_БД;User ID=имя_пользователя_БД;Password=пароль_пользователя" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

Comment: string sql = $"SELECT COUNT(email, password) FROM dle_users WHERE email = your_user_name AND password = your_password"; ПОТОМ ИДЕТ - MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, MydataBASE);

Answer (score 0):

```
     connectionString.Open();
           string sql = $"select * from dle_users where email = '{textBoxUserEmail.Text}' and password = '{sspass}' ";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connectionString);
                command.Prepare();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (textBoxUserEmail.Text == (string)command.ExecuteScalar())
                {
                    passlIsPass = true;
                if (connectionString != null && connectionString.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connectionString.Close();
                }

                else
                {
                passlIsPass = false;
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Логин или пароль введен неверно", "Внимание", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
```

Comment: внутри select лучше указать какое-то конкретное поле, иначе может случиться так, что там окажется не email. ExecuteScalar возвращает значение первой колонки первой строки.

Comment: @Grundy согласен